# Cannot Open Site Page in SharePoint 2013 (tag contains duplicate 'input' attributes)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sitepages

The Error I get is "Sorry, something went wrong. The tag contains duplicate 'input' attributes. Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator."

I have attempted to add '?contents=1' to the Site Page URL "http://servername/SitePages/MockupData.aspx?contents=1" and I get the following error: "The requested page was not found or could not be loaded."

Finally, the page cannot be opened in SPD, it says 'Server cannot open page. The tag contains duplicate 'input' attributes.' I have no idea how to open the page to fix it. I have access to Central Admin. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is realted to specific webpart within your site page and to trace this issue you should follow

- Try to check what's the latest web part has been added to your page before you got this issue.
- Try to deactivate its feature or retract its solution.
- Check the site page status.
- Repeate the previous steps for each web part within page to trace the issue.

You can also check this PowerSehll script to remove all wep arts in your page via powershell as Mainintnce Page do

```
$SPsite = Get-SPSite http://sharepoint-site/sites/admin/
$SPweb =  $SPsite.OpenWeb() 

$webpartmanager = $SPweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(($SPweb.Url + "default.aspx"),  [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

   $webpartsarray = @()

 For($i=0;$i -lt $webpartmanager.WebParts.Count;$i++)
  {
    if($webpartmanager.WebParts[$i].title -eq "Tip of the Day")  #Check for particular web part
     {
      $webpartsarray = $webpartsarray + $webpartmanager.WebParts[$i].ID
         }
  }

 $var=$webpartsarray.length
 #write-host $var

 for($j=0; $j -lt $var; $j++)
 {
 $webpartmanager.DeleteWebPart($webpartmanager.WebParts[$webpartsarray[$j]])

  # call CloseWebPart method to close the web part
 }

$SPweb.Update();
$SPweb.Dispose();
```

Ref: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/08/remove-webpart-programmatically-using-powershell.html

Comment: Wow. Thank you!